# A member of Congress subpoenas phone records and then release them: does this violate any US Laws?

Tags: privacy, subpoena, disclosure

If a member of Congress (e.g. Representative Schiff) subpoenas phone records of people (which is allowed) and releases them directly (in a report) or indirectly (leaked to press). Does this violate any (e.g. privacy) US Laws? Or, if there is law for a court subpoena to keep records private (e.g. a Grand Jury), did/could Congress exempt itself from these laws?

Comment: The *Speech and Debate Clause* only covers actions taken as a member, so the answer will depend on how the information is released. If it is part of a committee report, or entered into the record, the member is covered. That is why Mike Gravel read parts of the Pentagon Papers into the Record. He is also covered if he is engaged in "legislative activity." Otherwise, he is not covered (ie, Gravel was not covered when he leaked the Pentagon Papers to Beacon Press, since leaking is not a legislative activity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power to issue subpoenas is created by rule, so while an individual Congressman cannot currently issue a subpoena (instead a committee does), the rule can be changed. So it would be possible for a Congressman to issue a subpoena. He could release information obtained via the subpoena, and is immunized from legal repercussions by the [Speech and Debate Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_or_Debate_Clause) of the Constitution. However, there is no immunity against action by Congress, so he could be disciplined under [House](http://clerk.house.gov/legislative/house-rules.pdf) or [Senate](https://www.rules.senate.gov/imo/media/doc/CDOC-113sdoc18.pdf) rules. Disclosure might be a violation of House rule VII 3.(b)(2),
or committee rules established under Rule X(11)(f)
or XI 3.(a)(4), or other House rules or committee rules, which can be modified by majority vote. The House has no power to imprison its members, but they can be censured, or expelled by vote of 2/3 of the members (Art. 1 sec 5 of the Constitution).

Comment: But under current rules, is there anything wrong with the behavior?

Comment: I think so:  rule VII 3.(b)(2). But the House has the sole power to make that determination.

Comment: @user6726 Rule VII applies to House Records that have been archived, so it probably does not apply to this situation.

Comment: You're right, the rules are more narrowly focused, and there no general rule. I think we need more information about the hypothesized situation to be able to guess if there is a rule at present.

Answer (score 1):

If the heart of your question is, under the current rules, has anything been done wrong, I would say no. Other than the special case of a grand jury, our system allows/requires public dissemination of information regarding prosecutions.

Another answer refers to House Rule VII 3.(b)(2) - it is

> 2)  An  investigative  record  that  contains  personal  data 
>   relating  to  a  specific  living  person  (the  disclosure  of 
>   which  would  be  an  unwarranted  invasion  of  personal  privacy), 
>   an  administrative record relating to personnel, or a record relating
>   to a hearing that was closed  under  clause  2(g)(2)  of  rule  XI 
>   shall be made available if it has been in existence for 50 years.

My reading of that is  *if* the personal information is not made public as required by default in the immediately preceding section, it must be made available in 50 years. It does not require secrecy of anything for 50 years. It is rule about disclose, not a rule about not disclosing.

Comment: Plus, Rule VII is about the **archiving** of House Records. It is about what happens when the Clerk sends records to the Archivist for storage. Section 3 starts: "3(a) The Clerk shall authorize the Archivist..."

Comment: And public availability of those archived records 3. (a) The Clerk shall authorize the Archivist to make records delivered under clause 2 available for public use, subject to clause 4(b) and any order of the House.

Comment: Is the question about archived records? I assumed it is about stuff obtained in this session, and thus not in the Archive.

Comment: @Just a guy - correct - I conflated something that must be made public at the end of a session with something being made public now. Still no rule has been pointed to about the materials received in the investigation needing to be kept from the public. The only thing mentioned, Rule VII 3.(b)(2), is irrelevant to that.